# EN EXPRESS GENERE UN TOKEN Y LO ENVIO COMO RESPUESTA, LO TENGO QUE AGREGAR AL HEADER MANUALMENTE?

Tags: express, jwt, jsonwebtoken

Tengo este codigo, mi pregunta es que yo cuando obtengo el authorization me da undefined obviamente pero si lo paso en postman/insomnia en el header Authoriztation al token ahi funciona, el tema es que no se como hacer o si se hace desde el front la request por ejemplo

const token = axios('rutaquedevolveriaeltoken')

y luego si esa variable token la tengo que pasar a algun lado para luego acceder al header de authorization desde el back.

Basicamente estoy un poco confundido porque no se como hacer que llegue el token a Authorization o si llega automaticamente... Toy medio perdido, muchas gracias de antemano.

````
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const loginRouter = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/users/User');

loginRouter.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    // HERE I HAVE TO PUT get('authorization')... bla bla but from where and how I set Authorization? or is it atomatically?
    const { body } = req;
    const { username, password } = body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });
    const passwordCheck = user === null 
        ? false
        : await bcrypt.compare(password, user.passwordHash);

    if(!(user && passwordCheck)) { // if user and passwordCheck were true it wouldn't go into if.
        res.status(401).json({
            error: 'Invalid user or password'
        })
    }

    const userToToken = {
        id: user._id,
        username: user.username
    }

    const userToken = jwt.sign(userToToken, process.env.SECRET_KEY) // and third parameter could be { expiresIn: '1h' }

    res.send({
        name: user.name,
        username: user.username,
        tokenId: userToken
    })  //this parses into jwt 
})

module.exports = loginRouter;```
````

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. POR FAVOR NO USES MAYÚSCULAS. Como ves, se asimila a gritos y pues, no es la idea.

Comment: Un token es un código, usualmente cifrado, que generas en el servidor y envías al cliente de distintas formas (cookie, json, texto, cabecera http, etc). El cliente es el encargado de enviar de vuelta el token en cada solicitud en la cual sea requerido. Normalmente se establece un contrato o convenio para el envío de este token por parte del cliente, siendo el más común una cabecera `http` llamada `Authorization`. En el caso de tu código, si deseas usar la cabecera (`req.get('Authorization')`), entonces el token debes enviarlo desde el cliente (Postman, navegador, curl, etc.) en la cabecera.